# C FILE fgets function working in this code

Tags: c, pointers, file-handling, fgets

In my code I have a file named "f1.txt" and the text inside this file is a string "robin singh hero"

I have created a string [b]str[/b] of size [10] and a FILE type pointer variable *fp then assigned this pointer the address of the my file "f1.txt" from the fopen function.

Then I used fgets function which takes these three parameters (string,size,file pointer)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  char str[10];
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("f1.txt","r");

  if(fp == NULL)
  {
  printf("File does not exists");
  exit(1);
  }

  while (fgets(str,8,fp)!=NULL){
    printf("%s",str);
  }
  printf("\n");
  fclose(fp);
  puts(str);
  puts(str);
}
```

I mentioned size 8 so it means fgets will read first eight characters    (robin sin) from my file and store it to my string which is of size 10 and still 2 bytes of space in left in my string. then until my file reached a null it copies the next 8 characters (gh hero).

So I want to know this:
1. there are now 6 characters left, But the actual result is (robin singh hero)

2. What is happening here in the second step when there are only 6 characters left.
3. I wanted to know what's happened to my string str after the end of this while loop. so I did puts(str) and I am getting this value (ro) in the terminal.

Below is the actual result of this code:
robin singh hero

ro

ro

Comment: regarding: `printf("File does not exists");`  This is not (necessarily) true.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" )` as this will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated in the question that the file `f1.txt` contains this

```
robin singh hero
```

Now when below code gets executes

```
while (fgets(str,8,fp)!=NULL){
    printf("%s",str);
}
```

`fgets()` reads size minus one character i.e `7` character from file pointed by `fp` and store in `str`. So in first iteration `printf()` statement prints

```
robin s
```

then in second iteration it again tries to read `7` character i.e `printf()` statement prints

```
ingh he
```

and then again it tries to read `7` characters but there are only `3` char(including `\n`, if it is) so `printf()` statement prints

```
ro
```

Now the below code segment

```
printf("\n"); /* prints \n character on console */
fclose(fp); /* closes the file */
puts(str); /* when above while loop terminates str has ro in it, hence it prints ro on console */
puts(str); /* prints ro on console */
```

since you have called `puts()` twice, it prints `ro` twice.

From the manual page of [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> `fgets()` *reads in **at most one less than size characters from
>   stream and stores them into the buffer** pointed to by s. Reading
>   stops after an EOF or a newline*. *If a newline is read, it is stored
>   into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the
>   last character in the buffer.*

Also note that `void main() {}` is not the standard `main()` prototype. You should be using

```
int main(void) {

   return 0;
}
```

From the C standard
**5.1.2.2.1  Program  startup**

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The
>   implementation declares no prototype  for  this  function.   It  shall
>   be  defined  with  a  *return  type  of int and  with  no parameters*:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> or
>
> with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ }
> ```